# On imageclick open/expand image to fullscreen

Tags: android, imageview, xamarin, coverflow

Like a coverflow effect i want my image to flip on click witch the code below does but when the animation is finished i want the image to expand and fill the screen. How do i do that? Do i have to use a new acitivty and a new axml screen?

```
 ImageView i = (ImageView) FindViewById(args.Position);
            ObjectAnimator anim = (ObjectAnimator)AnimatorInflater.LoadAnimator(this, Resource.Animator.flipping);

            anim.SetTarget(i);
            anim.SetDuration(3000);
            anim.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a fullscreen Custom Dialog like this:

```
Dialog dialog=new Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Dark_NoTitleBar_FullScreen)
```

use a .xml(yes, you have to create one) and set it to the dialog like this:

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.YOURDIALOG);
```

and it the .xml of your layout, set the imageview to match the root parent.
and to display the dialog:

```
dialog.show();
```

Comment: its the android R class

Comment: Maybe thats not available with xamarin?

Comment: Oh i see i need to write the hole Resource instead of R :)

Comment: Nothing happens. Do i have to make the dialog accualy appear in some way? cause now the debugger just walkes past it but nothing happens.

Comment: @DanielGustafsson if everything else is correct: `dialog.show();`

Comment: example of a xml dialog please